# Does ordering shaloch manos before Purim fulfill the mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, internet, purim, shlichus-agency, mishloach-manot

I am wondering whether ordering shaloch manos for someone online actually fulfills the mitzvah of mishloach manos. [This](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/261101/jewish/The-Laws-of-Sending-Gifts-on-Purim.htm) page says:

> To fulfill the mitzvah of Mishloach Manot, one must send it during the
>   day of Purim. One does not fulfill the mitzvah by sending it the
>   previous or following night.

Does this mean that the shaloch manos must be ordered during Purim day, delivered during Purim day, or both?

Is there any reason to believe that the big shaloch manos sites are doing something special whereby their deliveries would actually fulfill the mitzvah?

Comment: Thelink in your question answers your concern, actually. It has a few scenarios, actually, and I think it clarifies and answers your question very well. I'm not sure what else you need to know.

Comment: @DanF Do you mean on a different page? The page I linked does not obviously contain answers to my questions. (Except, i guess, for an implication that the shaloch manos need to be /delivered/ Purim.)

Comment: A Purim comment, when I read Shaloch, My french brain interpret "3" and I say, 3 is for Machatsith Hashekel, manot are 2X2 only.

Answer (score 1):

#### First, it was examined whether to give Matanoth Laevionim before Purim

Magen Avraham ([O.C. 694 saif koton 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3074)) says in name of the [Maor](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37957&st=&pgnum=509&hilite=) not to give before purim because you need to make sure they do not eat the manoth before Purim. (This is about Matanoth Laevionim).

#### In the case of Mishloach Manoth

It is the same for Mishloach Manoth (S.A. O.C. [695, 4, Rema](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3076) and Magen Avraham s.k. 13).
The din is the same.

#### The origin of this questioning

Here is the text of the ***Baal Hamaor***.

I'll give an introduction and a rough translation. The Gemara talk about the current situation. We have to read the Megila in both villages and cities on 14 Adar. The explanation is "בזמן הזה הואיל ומסתכלין בה אין קורין אותה אלא בזמנה
"
There is a vaste range of interpretations in Rishonim. The Rif says that poor mans wait Mikra megilah to get money of Purim. The baal Hamaor objects that we are able to do that at any day. Rabenu Efraim solve the problem. If they receive the money too early, they will consume it before Purim.

כתב הרי"ף ז"ל הואיל ועיניהם של עניים נשואים למקרא מגילה  וכו' וראיתי לרבינו אפרים שפירש לפרק זו הקושיא ואמר בזמן הזה שישראל מיוסרים בדקדוקי עניות אי יהבינן להו מתנות בי"א ובי"ב ובי"ג אזלי ואכלי להו ביומא ההוא ושמחת פורים אינה נוהגת אלא בזמנה ובטלה לה שמחה. ואי אמרת ליקרו בי"א ולא ליתיב להו מידי עד יום י"ד, וט"ו, כיון דחזי עניים דקרי מגילה ולא יהבו להו מידי, מיאשי ואזלי להו בדוכתא אחריתי וקא בטלה מצוות פורים מהני דקרי בי"א ובי"ג בי"ג

As long as we know that they do not consum before purim, it is allowed to give to the Shaliach before Purim.

But this explanation appear unuitable for Mishloach Manoth, but the Levushey Serad said very clearly that for Mishloah Manoth too, there is concern that they are going to eat it before the Mishte.

#### Conclusion: Does ordering shaloch manos before Purim fulfill the mitzvah?

### Yes, it is possible, *if the deliverer goes on time*.

Comment: Interesting answer, but does not address the question of whether your individual Purim mitzvah (i.e., to dispatch shaloch manos) can be performed before Purim.

Comment: @SAH The Din of shlichuth is known in torah. if I make someone shaliach, I can do this 340 days before purim. I think more if you have a friend, you can give the manot yourself before purim, and ask it to eat this at the mishte and not before and it is perfect, also 340 days before purim. Because all the problem is: perhaps it will be consumed before the mishte (but I am not sure)